# Does a dialog have a maximum size?

Tags: android

I am using a dialog to display a 7 images. the problem that the dialog is displaying 6 images perfectly and the 7th one (on the right of the 6 images) is truncated. Even if  I replace the 7th image with a button, it is still truncated as if the dialog has fixed size. Does not the dialog expand according to the views I add?  This is really anoying

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);// this would refer to the context of the current activity
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.origpickgame);
            ColorDrawable dialogColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.GRAY);
            dialogColor.setAlpha(100);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(dialogColor);
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Comment: you can put images in horizontalscrollview..and if the images r of fixed size let's say 50*50 then it will truncated as even if the dialog has fixed size.